# Access user profile data in another PHP web application

Tags: php, xml, json, web-services

I'm using two php application. In the first application users can register and add profile data. The profile data viewed in a preview mode in 1st application. In the 2nd application uses the same users from 1st application, in this case i would like to show the profile view in 2nd application without database access of 1st app. With this requirement which method is best? How can access the preview mode in 2nd app? Any conversion/formatting required?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Web Service for access data from 1st app.

Web service is safe for transfer secure data such as user & password.

For example when user wants to viewed profile. Application sent user & password & request(viewed Profile) with web service client to web service server (1st application) then web service server processed request and return data to client.

SOAP is good web service to use for this.

More details: http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

Comment: Not webservice. Is it possible to convert the profile view to html page and can i use that html in 2nd app? HTML publishing mode.?

Comment: Yes you can but it's not good. You can create php file on 1st application and pass user & password to this file then it return html file for display. for example: echo file_get_contents("http://oneapp.com/profile?user=test&pass=test"); I say again this method is not good.